# How do I find out which font shapes and series are used in my document?

Tags: fonts

Is there a way to get a list of all encoding/family/series/shape combinations that are actually used in a document that you have the sources of? You know, like the `OT1/fvm/m/n` strings you get when a particular font is missing.

This is important when you want to change to a commercial font and need to know what weights and variants you actually need to buy. Like: "Do I actually need the demi-bold small caps italics?"

And since many font changes are not done by hand with `\emph`s and whatnot, things can easily get a little confusing in a longer document.

Comment: Does the list of fonts in `Acrobat Reader-> Document Properties->Fonts` help?

Comment: @percusse No, not really. It usually doesn't contain shape and weight information. It's useful when I want to find out what font families are used but that at least I do know of my own documents ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

add

```
\showoutput
```

to your document, your log file then has lots of stuff like

```
......\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x0.0, glue set - 345.0fil
.......\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x345.0
........\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x345.0, glue set 290.04158fil
.........\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 G
.........\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 r
.........\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.........\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
```

which you can then filter eg on a bash command line as

```
$ grep -o   "\\\\[A-Za-z0-9]*/[A-Za-z0-9]*/[A-Za-z0-9]*/[A-Za-z0-9]*/[0-9.]* " abc3.log | sort -u
\OML/cmm/m/it/10 
\OMX/cmex/m/n/5 
\OT1/cmr/bx/n/14.4 
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10
```

That is search for all instances of strings of the right form sort them and remove duplicates, revealing I just used four fonts in my test document.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was searching for! Actually, `grep -o "\\\\[A-Za-z0-9]*/[A-Za-z0-9]*/[A-Za-z0-9]*/[A-Za-z0-9]*" abc.log | sort -u` will also only find font strings and already get rid of the different sizes so the output is much smaller and can be understood at a glance. `grep -o "\\\\[A-Za-z0-9]*/[A-Za-z0-9]*/[A-Za-z0-9]*/[A-Za-z0-9]*/[0-9.]* " abc.log | grep -o "\\\\[A-Za-z0-9]*/[A-Za-z0-9]*/[A-Za-z0-9]*/[A-Za-z0-9]*" | sort -u` for the paranoid.

Comment: Or ``\\``, for some versions of `grep`, instead of ``\\\\``

Comment: @egreg I think it's always just two \ for _grep_ the difference is the command line (which is why I mentioned bash) bash grabs one level of \-quoting before grep sees the string.